# ASP.NET MVC 5 - order notification; receive real-time alerts for new customer orders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub

We have two different applications in ASP.NET MVC 5.

The first application is a website to place an order by user; the user has to sign up to the account to place an order, and the other is the dashboard, where admins can have all the details of the orders placed by customers.

These two applications have been hosted on separate domains; we have SignalR hubs in both projects.

I want to know what I can do to get notifications on the dashboard when a customer places an order on the website and when the admin accepts the order, so the user receives the notification on their account?

Comment: What have you tried?  Any errors or exceptions? Please show your attempt.

Comment: @mxmissile I haven't tried once to connect because I'm a bit confused about how I can make them communicate with each other so the website hub can listen to the dashboard and the dashboard can listen to the website.

Ive searched on Google and found something, but I don't know which one to follow:
1) SignalR Hub API
2) SQL Dependency

I have millions of records, so please suggest which option is better.